# Utility of FetchSize and PageSize in Reader Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

What is the difference between the propertie "FetchSize" and "PageSize" in Spring Batch ?
The PageSize is the number of rows to retrieve at a time ?
The FetchSize is number of DB calls ?

If my query return 10000 rows, what is the best setting ? 
If i put PageSize to 1000 and FetchSize to 1000, can you confirm i just need 10 calls for return all rows ?
So if i upgrade the number of the propertie PageSize (for example 10.000), the number of DB call is just 1 so running time of the batch is better ?

Answer (score 3):

That's correct. With `pageSize=1000` and `fetchSize=500`, there will be in theory 2 database calls to fetch a single page.

However, the `fetchSize` is just a hint to the database driver and can be ignored. So you need to check your database driver's documentation to make sure it behaves as expected with regards to this parameter.