# Data discrepancy in spring batch

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am using the spring batch to transfer data from DB and index them in a Solr server. I noticed the exact amount of data records are indexed in the Solr. But when I checked the data, I noticed I had duplicated rows in my Solr. Regarding the exact number of rows in both DB and Solr, it appears the Spring Batch somehow writes one record multiple times instead of the new legitimate records.

I changed the target to write everything into a CSV file to ensure it was not the Solr issue. And I could repeat the problem. But, unfortunately, it means I have duplicated rows in my CSV file too.

The following is the snippet of my code that I made as simple as possible. I have to use some paging for reading my database because I have around 20M rows of data, and reading all will crash my servers.

```
    @Bean
    public Step indexingStep() {
        // @formatter:off
        return stepBuilder
            .get("stepOne")
            .<AddressInfo, AddressInfo> chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(addressReader())
            .writer(itemWriter())
        .build();
        // @formatter:on
    }

@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<AddressInfo> itemWriter() {
  return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<AddressInfo>()
      .name("personItemWriter")
      .resource(new FileSystemResource(
          "data.csv"))
      .delimited().delimiter(", ")
      .names(new String[] { "addressDetailPid", "streetLocalityPid", 
             "localityPid"}).build();
}
@Bean
public ItemReader<AddressInfo> addressReader() {

    // @formatter:off
    HibernatePagingItemReader<AddressInfo> hibernatePagingItemReader =  new HibernatePagingItemReaderBuilder<AddressInfo>()
            .name("addReader")
            .sessionFactory(sessionFactory)
            .queryString("select f from AddressInfo f")
            .saveState(false)
            .pageSize(pageSize)
        .build();
    hibernatePagingItemReader.setUseStatelessSession(true);
    return hibernatePagingItemReader;
    // @formatter:on    
}
```

UPDATE: I tried the "JpaPagingItemReader" with the same issue. It seems the paging mechanism causes this issue. When I used a cursor-based reader in most cases, it worked perfectly. But I had to partition my data to prevent the OOM exception. I don't believe the Spring Batch has this fundamental problem, and only I see it.

This is my environment if it helps:
jdk11
Spring Boot 2.4.1
DB: Postgres 9
Solr: 8.1

SOLVED:
It looks, I needed to add "order by" in my JPQL as follows:

```
@Bean
    public JpaPagingItemReader<AddressInfo> itemReader() {
        // @formatter:off
        return new JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder<AddressInfo>()
                    .name("creditReader")
                    .entityManagerFactory(emf)
                    .queryString("select c from AddressInfo c order by c.addressDetailPid ")
                    .pageSize(pageSize)
                    .build();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of your item reader? Does `AddressInfo` implement `equals` and `hashcode` correctly ? It would be helpful if you provide a minimal example with an embedded db to be able to debug the case.

Comment: I am using Lombok annotation "@Data" on top of AddressInfo and it creates the right equals and hashcode methods for the bean.

Comment: The issue is the "HibernatePagingItemReader". When I use "HibernateCursorItemReaderBuilder", I see correct data in the target. Now, my problem is how to fix the OOM issue with "HibernateCursorItemReaderBuilder". It must read all of the 20M rows at once now.

Answer (score 1):

The `HibernateCursorItemReader` is configurable with a `fetchSize` to limit the number of rows fetched per database round trip. The 20M rows won't be loaded in-memory at once, but will be streamed in a cursor-based approach.

The `chunkSize` value of your chunk-oriented step is also key here. The JVM should at least have enough memory to a load a single chunk of items in memory. Processed chunks will be garbage collected.

Comment: Does This "fetchsize" work like page size? Because it seems,  paging causes that data discrepancy.

Comment: No, it gave me an OOM error. If paging worked, it would be great.

Comment: I am using Postgres.  Does the database engine matter in paging?

Comment: `pageSize` and `fetchSize` are different, please check this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041942. The database engine should not matter, you just need to make sure the driver streams results instead of reading all records at once, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55400654/5019386.